# Elastic and dynamic update of _id value

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana

I am looking to update roughly 2000 document `_id`'s in my elastic cluster.  I understand SQL much better than I do Elastic's API.

I was wondering if someone might be able to help translate the following SQL into a JSON query I can execute in Kibana:

```
update Persons p2 set p2.id = (select p.metadata.id from Persons where p.id = p2.id)
 where p2.id <> p2.metadata.id
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include more information on what you expect your query to achieve, including sample data, please? From the first glance, your SQL statement seems faulty in different ways. First, it does not update `_id` at all, but from your question, that is what you'd like to achieve? Second, it uses `p2` in the inner query*s `where` clause, where it is out of scope. Try to add a working [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in SQL or better describe your problem with example data in Elasticsearch.

Comment: @buddemat - Translating this to an easy SELECT statement, it would look like:
`SELECT * FROM 
Persons p2 
WHERE p2.id = (select p.metadata.id from Persons where p.id = p2.id)
AND p2.id <> p2.metadata.id`

Comment: @buddemat - Please see my submitted answer, this is what worked for my original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a while I was able to solve the problem using the ES Java API by doing the following:

```
SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest();
SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder bq = boolQuery().must(existsQuery("metadata.id"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("doc['_id'].value != doc['metadata.id'].value;");
 
ScriptQueryBuilder sqb = scriptQuery(new Script(Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TYPE, "painless", sb.toString(), new HashMap<>()));

bq.filter(sqb);
ssb.query(bq);
sr.source(ssb);
LOGGER.debug("Request=" + sr.source());
```